Content-Disposition header not available in frontend
I have the following api endpoint in my backend:
  @ApiPost('download/:id', { type: OutputStatusDto, description: 'Download file from URL' })
  async downloadFile(@Param() params: InputIdDto, @Res() res: Response) {
    const file = await this._fileService.findOne({ where: { id: params.id } });
    const { buffer } = await this._fileService.downloadFile(file.url);

    res.set({
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
      'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${file.originalname}`,
      'Content-Length': buffer.length,
    });

    res.end(buffer);
  }

Now in my frontent I do the following:
export const downloadFile = (id: string) =>
  axios
    .get<any>(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/stripe/file/download/${id}`, {
      responseType: 'blob',
    })
    .then((res: AxiosResponse<any>) => {
      console.log(res);
      return {
        data: res.data,
        filename: '...',
      };
    });

Unfortunately, the Content-Disposition header is not visible:

I wanted to use it to extract filename. Why it does not work?

console.log() doesn't always show everything. Have you tried actually getting the header value? res.headers['content-disposition']

This question is similar to: Unable to get custom headers with Axios in reactJs. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
